# How to restrict fountain blocks to coming out by clicking at one place/object instead of from whole screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a query though, As we click anywhere on the screen and the fountain works but my goal is to restrict fountain work by clicking on a particular position/object on the screen. For example, let's assume a place or a 150X150px image on the center of the screen and the fountain should work only when I click on the image and nowhere else. I will appreciate the help. Thanks

```js
//-------------------------------- For Squares-------------

var d = document, $d = $(d),
    w = window, $w = $(w),
    wWidth = $w.width(), wHeight = $w.height(),
    credit = $('.credit > a'),
    particles = $('.particles'),
    particleCount = 0,
    maxTime = 10,
    sizes = [
        75
    ],
    colors = [
      '#f44336', '#e91e63', '#9c27b0', '#673ab7', '#3f51b5',
      '#2196f3', '#03a9f4', '#00bcd4', '#009688', '#4CAF50',
      '#8BC34A', '#CDDC39', '#FFEB3B', '#FFC107', '#FF9800',
      '#FF5722', '#795548', '#9E9E9E', '#607D8B', '#777777'
    ],
    
    mouseX = $w.width() / 2, mouseY = $w.height() / 2;

function updateParticleCount () {
  $('.particle-count > .number').text(particleCount);
};

$w
.on( 'resize' , function () {
  wWidth = $w.width();
  wHeight = $w.height();
});

$d
.on( 'mousemove touchmove' , function ( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  mouseX = event.clientX;
  mouseY = event.clientY;
  if( !!event.originalEvent.touches ) {
    mouseX = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX;
    mouseY = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY;
  }
})
.on( 'mousedown touchstart' , function( event ) {
  if( event.target === credit.get(0) ){
    return;
  }
  mouseX = event.clientX;
  mouseY = event.clientY;
  if( !!event.originalEvent.touches ) {
    mouseX = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX;
    mouseY = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY;
  }

 var counter = 0;

   var timer = setInterval(function () {
    if (counter < maxTime) {
      createParticle( event );
    } else {
      clearInterval( timer );
      counter = 0;
    }
    counter++;
    
  }, 1000 / 20);
  
  $d.
  on('mouseup mouseleave touchend touchcancel touchleave', function () {
    clearInterval( timer );
  });
});


function createParticle ( event ) {
  var particle = $('<div class="particle">' + getSymbol() + '</div>'),
      size = sizes[Math.floor(Math.random() * sizes.length)],
      color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)],
      negative = size/2,
      speedHorz = Math.random() * 10,
      speedUp = Math.random() * 25,
      spinVal = 360 * Math.random(),
      spinSpeed = ((12 * Math.random())) * (Math.random() <=.5 ? -1 : 1),
      otime,
      time = otime = (1 + (.5 * Math.random())) * 1000,
      top = (mouseY - negative),
      left = (mouseX - negative),
      direction = Math.random() <=.5 ? -1 : 1 ,
      life = 10;
  
  particle
  .css({
    height: size + 'px',
    width: size + 'px',
    top: top + 'px',
    left: left + 'px',
    background: color,
    transform: 'rotate(' + spinVal + 'deg)',
    webkitTransform: 'rotate(' + spinVal + 'deg)'
  })
  .appendTo( particles );
  particleCount++;
  updateParticleCount();
  
  var particleTimer = setInterval(function () {
    time = time - life;
    left = left - (speedHorz * direction);
    top = top - speedUp;
    speedUp = Math.min(size, speedUp - 1);
    spinVal = spinVal + spinSpeed;
  
    
    particle
    .css({
      height: size + 'px',
      width: size + 'px',
      top: top + 'px',
      left: left + 'px',
      opacity: ((time / otime)/2) + 1.0,
      transform: 'rotate(' + spinVal + 'deg)',
      webkitTransform: 'rotate(' + spinVal + 'deg)'
    });
    
    if( time <= 0 || left <= -size || left >= wWidth + size || top >= wHeight + size ) {
      particle.remove();
      particleCount--;
      updateParticleCount();
      clearInterval(particleTimer);
    }
  }, 1000 / 50);  
}





//-------------------------------- For Circles-------------

var d = document, $d = $(d),
    w = window, $w = $(w),
    wWidth = $w.width(), wHeight = $w.height(),
    credit = $('.credit > a'),
    particles2 = $('.particles2'),
    particle2Count = 0,
    maxTime = 10,
    sizes = [
        75
    ],
    colors = [
      '#f44336', '#e91e63', '#9c27b0', '#673ab7', '#3f51b5',
      '#2196f3', '#03a9f4', '#00bcd4', '#009688', '#4CAF50',
      '#8BC34A', '#CDDC39', '#FFEB3B', '#FFC107', '#FF9800',
      '#FF5722', '#795548', '#9E9E9E', '#607D8B', '#777777'
    ],
    
    mouseX = $w.width() / 2, mouseY = $w.height() / 2;

function updateParticle2Count () {
  $('.particle2-count > .number').text(particle2Count);
};

$w
.on( 'resize' , function () {
  wWidth = $w.width();
  wHeight = $w.height();
});

$d
.on( 'mousemove touchmove' , function ( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  mouseX = event.clientX;
  mouseY = event.clientY;
  if( !!event.originalEvent.touches ) {
    mouseX = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX;
    mouseY = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY;
  }
})
.on( 'mousedown touchstart' , function( event ) {
  if( event.target === credit.get(0) ){
    return;
  }
  mouseX = event.clientX;
  mouseY = event.clientY;
  if( !!event.originalEvent.touches ) {
    mouseX = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX;
    mouseY = event.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY;
  }

  var counter = 0;

   var timer = setInterval(function () {
    if (counter < maxTime) {
      createParticle2( event );
    } else {
      clearInterval( timer );
      counter = 0;
    }
    counter++;
    
  }, 1000 / 20);
  
  $d.
  on('mouseup mouseleave touchend touchcancel touchleave', function () {
    clearInterval( timer );
  });
});


function createParticle2 ( event ) {
  var particle2 = $('<div class="particle2">' + getSymbol() + '</div>'),
      size = sizes[Math.floor(Math.random() * sizes.length)],
      color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)],
      negative = size/2,
      speedHorz = Math.random() * 10,
      speedUp = Math.random() * 25,
      spinVal = 360 * Math.random(),
      spinSpeed = ((12 * Math.random())) * (Math.random() <=.5 ? -1 : 1),
      otime,
      time = otime = (1 + (.5 * Math.random())) * 1000,
      top = (mouseY - negative),
      left = (mouseX - negative),
      direction = Math.random() <=.5 ? -1 : 1 ,
      life = 10;
  
  particle2
  .css({
    height: size + 'px',
    width: size + 'px',
    top: top + 'px',
    left: left + 'px',
    background: color,
    transform: 'rotate(' + spinVal + 'deg)',
    webkitTransform: 'rotate(' + spinVal + 'deg)'
  })
  .appendTo( particles2 );
  particle2Count++;
  updateParticle2Count();
  
  var particle2Timer = setInterval(function () {
    time = time - life;
    left = left - (speedHorz * direction);
    top = top - speedUp;
    speedUp = Math.min(size, speedUp - 1);
    spinVal = spinVal + spinSpeed;
    
    
    particle2
    .css({
      height: size + 'px',
      width: size + 'px',
      top: top + 'px',
      left: left + 'px',
      opacity: ((time / otime)/2) + 1.0,
      transform: 'rotate(' + spinVal + 'deg)',
      webkitTransform: 'rotate(' + spinVal + 'deg)'
    });
    
    if( time <= 0 || left <= -size || left >= wWidth + size || top >= wHeight + size ) {
      particle2.remove();
      particle2Count--;
      updateParticle2Count();
      clearInterval(particle2Timer);
    }
  }, 1000 / 50);  
}
function getSymbol() {
  var symbols = "12X34Y5Z+x=-%";
  return symbols.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * symbols.length));
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:300');
.particle-count {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 25px 0;
}

.particles > .particle {
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: white;
}

.particles > .particle.small {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
.particles > .particle.normal {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}
.particles > .particle.big {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
.particles > .particle.bigger {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

.particles {
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  font-size: 48px;
  text-align: center;
}

/**-----------------------------------------------------------------**/
.particle2-count {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 25px 0;
}

.particles2 > .particle2 {
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: white;
}

.particles2 > .particle2.small {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
.particles2 > .particle2.normal {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}
.particles2 > .particle2.big {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
.particles2 > .particle2.bigger {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

.particles2 {
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  font-size: 48px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
<body>
  Click for particles
  <div class="particles">
  </div>
  <div class="particles2">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you begun reading the Firebase docs? It is not all that difficult to set up Firebase and to structure and sync your data, but you have to read first. We can't do this for you.

Comment: @Jerome read the first version of the question and you will see why I made my comment. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44249696/revisions

Comment: @wlh ah, gotcha :)